# Was Antipas a person or is the word a symbolism for Christian?

Tags: new-testament, revelation

In the Revelation chapter two verse thirteen Jesus refers to Antipas being martyred:

Revelation 2:13  KJV

> I know thy works, and where thou dwellest, even where Satan's seat is: and thou holdest fast my name, and hast not denied my faith, even in those days wherein Antipas was my faithful martyr, who was slain among you, where Satan dwelleth.

Mickelson lists the original Greek word as:

Ἀντίπας Antipas (an-tee'-pas) n/p. Antipas, a Christian

The Greek revised version also uses that same word  αντιπας and is also defined as a Christian.

So I am confused as to whether Jesus is referring to a specific person named Antipas or simply saying one of his followers, was slain among them.

Comment: Huh, is it the same word in Herod Antipas' name? There it means 'like the father'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Many Christian traditions believe](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/hastings/dictv1/Page_107.html) Saint Antipas to be the Antipas referred to in the Book of Revelation (Revelation 2:13) as the "faithful martyr" of Pergamon, "where Satan dwells".

According to Christian tradition, John the Apostle ordained Antipas as bishop of Pergamon during the reign of the Roman emperor Domitian. The traditional account goes on to say Antipas was martyred in ca. 92 AD by burning in a brazen bull-shaped altar used for casting out demons worshiped by the local population.

Comment: @ vs06 I am aware of the story of Antipas of Pergamon, however the word Antipas was in use prior to that as is noted by curiousdanni in her comment. There it has a much different translation than as used in Revelation 2:13. My consternation stems from the fact that the word is translated differently in places.